# ~ろ・~ろも・思うて・~たった in 越後 dialect (新潟弁?)

Tags: dialects

At the start of this book the family are stated to be from 亀田町{かめだまち}, an area which is now part of 新潟市{にいがたし}, but it's also set historically (1919 at the start of the book). I'm presuming the specific dialect used is 新潟弁 but I'm not 100% sure.

Here, the father of the family responds to his wife's comment that the name he's picked for their daughter sounds like a boy's name:

> 「お前はそういうろと思うてたったろも」

From what I can understand of 越後方言{えちごほうげん} from the internet:

1. そういうだろう→そういうろ (and this ending could also be だろ・ろー in some cases?)
2. 思って→思うて (from the context, although I'm not entirely sure on this)
3. いた→いたった→たった　（Described as "過去重複形" on Wikipedia and I am assuming that the い is dropping out of 〜ていた)
4. けど→ろも (Also ども could be used here?)

So the meaning is, unless I'm hopelessly off-base roughly "I thought you'd say that..." (and he goes on to explain his reasoning for the name).  I'd like confirmation that this is correct, and any additional information on nuances I might be missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about 新潟弁 or 越後弁 but I think your interpretation is correct as far as I can see from [here](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%96%B0%E6%BD%9F%E5%BC%81):

1. そういうろ

   > 4 推量
   >   推量は「終止形＋ロー」によって表される。終止形の末音が「ル」の場合は促音化する。
   >   ソト サーメロー。ハヨ ヘーレテ。（外、寒いだろう。早く入れよ）

   推量 ＞＞＞ 終止形+ロー
    寒い+ロー ＞＞＞ さむいろー ＞＞＞ さーめろー (さーめ is the 終止形 in
   新潟弁???)
    そう言う+ロー ＞＞＞ そういうろー
2. 思うて

   > 1 活用
   >   ~(中略)~
   >   連用形においてウ音便があるが、これは西日本方言的な特徴といえる。
   >   コーテ クル（買ってくる）、ノーナッシモタ（なくなってしまった）

   連用形 ＞＞＞ ウ音便
    買って ＞＞＞ こーて
    思って ＞＞＞ おもーて
3. たった

   > 3 時制
   >   時制は日本語の他の諸方言と同じく現在時制・過去時制の２種類があるが、過去時制には「連用形＋タッタ～ダッタ」>のように過去形を重複させた特殊な形式を持つ。~(中略)~
   >   サッキ スズキクンガ コーエンニ イタッタヨ。（さっき鈴木君が公園にいたよ）

   過去時制 ＞＞＞ 連用形+たった/だった
    い(る)+たった ＞＞＞ いたった
    思ってい(る)+たった ＞＞＞
   おもうていたった （＞＞＞ おもうてたった, dropping the い）
4. ろも

   > 7 接続
   >   用言の接続形式には以下のようなものがある。
   >   ~(中略)~
   >   終止形＋ロモ（…けれども；逆接）
   >   ソノ エーガ ミタロモ オモッショネカッタ。（その映画、見たけど面白くなかった）

   逆接 ＞＞＞ 終止形+ロモ
    見た+けど ＞＞＞ 見た+ろも ＞＞＞ みたろも (I don't know why it's
   not みたったろも)
    ～～いた+けど ＞＞＞ ～～いた+ろも ＞＞＞ ～～いたったろも

Comment: 俺もそれで悩んだことがある...　数字の後に点があるとリストだと思い込んで、項目の間に改行とかが入ってるからか、毎回リストが1からスタート... 前のリストの続きだということを認識させる方法が分かれば解決するはずなのだが...

Comment: Put two spaces at the beginning of each paragraph if you want it to nest under the previous list item.